# How to restore sql+txt dump?

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I have some dumps created with the following command:

```
mysqldump --host=$host --user=$dbuser --password=$dbpass --tab=$backupdir/$dbname $dbname
```

That created couple files table.sql/table.txt with the structure in the first (that can can be installed with `mysql -u username -p database_name < table.sql`) and the rows in the second.

How can I import the rows with that files ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474210/easily-import-a-mysql-tab-dump

Comment: Thank you, that's what I needed